# CORS issue with PUT request from reactjs to asp.netCore api

Tags: sql, reactjs, asp.net-core, iis, react-hooks

I am working on a Reactjs app with Asp.netCore API with Sql database
deployed to IIS server.
All the operation is working except PUT operation on the task
it break with CORS error and the request is not reaching the backend, I tested it locally and it's working fine. Tested using Postman and it's working too even the deployed version is working with postman. I can't figure out what's the issue or from where I should start debugging.

**startup.cs**

```
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy(name: CorsPolicy, builder =>
           {
               builder.WithOrigins(FrontEnd_URL).SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => 
               true).AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials();
           }));
       }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(CorsPolicy);


            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapHub<TrelloHub>("/trello");

            });
        }
```

**TaskController**

```
    [Route("/api/tasks")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TasksController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly ITaskService _taskService;

        public TasksController(ITaskService taskService , IMapper mapper)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
            _taskService = taskService;
        }

        [HttpPut("{id:int}", Name = "UpdateTask")]
        public async Task<String> UpadateTask([FromBody]TaskDto taskdto, int id)
        {
            
            var taskModel = _mapper.Map<Task>(taskdto);
            return await _taskService.UpadateTask(id , taskModel);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first check IIS server logs. it can help you a lot, also look at the request headers of the reactjs client `origin:`  header exactly and add it to the allowed origins

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, I check the Event Viewer and it shows error while casting dateTime attributes to string